# xsim: Headline of \printsolution when exercise/name has been changed

Tags: xsim, translate, translations

I want the word "Question" (or the german word "Aufgabe") instead of "Exercise", so I set

```
\xsimsetup{
exercise/name=\XSIMtranslate{question},
}
```

But `\printsolutions` gives me still "Solutions to the **Exercises**"

Shouldn’t it be ”Solutions to the *Questions*” here? *Automatically....*

*What do I have to do to get the correct headline (automatically)?*

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[no-files]{xsim}[2020/02/23]

\xsimsetup{
exercise/name=\XSIMtranslate{question},
}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}[subtitle=(find $x$)]
\begin{enumerate}
\item   $x-1=0$ 
\item   $x-2=0$ 
\item   $x-3=0$ 
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercise}
%
\begin{solution}
\begin{enumerate}
\item   $x=1$ 
\item   $x=2$ 
\item   $x=3$
\end{enumerate}
\end{solution}

\printsolutions

\section*{Shouldn't it be "Solutions to the Questions" here?}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, maybe it should. Or maybe there should at least be an option `exercises/name` (notice the plural). Anyway, for the time being you need to set the plural via `\SetExerciseParameter`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xsim}

\xsimsetup{
  exercise/name=\XSIMtranslate{question}
}
\SetExerciseParameter{exercise}{exercises-name}{\XSIMtranslate{questions}}

\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}
\end{exercise}
\begin{solution}
\end{solution}

\printsolutions

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very good, Mr. Niederberger. ;)